# Is there any way to show elements from a listview one by one and scroll through them?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

Currently in my calendar section, i get events from google calendar, and the items are show like this.
[image: The listview have height auto, and show all elements]

what I want is show this elements, one by one and adjust the height so its fits the element content which you are seeing and then scroll through the list to see the others elements.

And everytime you scroll down the listview is going to readjust the height to fit the new element.

Something like this

[image: Showing just first element]

Then you scroll

[image: Showing just the second element with a new height]

But i dont know who to do this, if i bind the height to the wrapper of the element in the datatemplate just ignore the bind. And you can scroll through the elements without select them, so i cant modify the template for selected items, or bind with the selected item.

Searching i have found some ways to modify the item height to the parent height, but that's not what i want, is the opposite.

my xaml

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" 
                      x:Name="DatosEvento"
                      Margin="5"
                      MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Calendar}"
                      Height="250"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Eventos}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="350" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="CornflowerBlue" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Nombre Organizador" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Organizer.DisplayName}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Correo Organizador" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Organizer.Email}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Nombre Evento" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Summary}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Estado" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fecha Inicio dd/mm/yyyy" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Start.DateTime}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fecha actualización" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Updated, ConverterCulture={x:Static SystemGlobalization:CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fecha Fin dd/mm/yyyy" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=End.DateTime}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Margin="2">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Enlace" Background="Gray"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HtmlLink}" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" MouseDown="TextBlockHiperLink_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Line X1="10" X2="300" Margin="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple template:

```
     <ListView   SelectedIndex="0">
   <ListView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
     <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}" />
      <ScrollBar Minimum="0"
                 Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=Items.Count,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ToRealCount}}"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 ViewportSize="0.5" />
     </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
   </ListView.Template>
   <ListView.Items>
    <Rectangle Fill="Violet"
               Width="100"
               Height="100" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Aqua"
               Width="100"
               Height="100" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Green"
               Width="100"
               Height="100" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red"
               Width="100"
               Height="100" />
   </ListView.Items>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ListView>
```

Converter :

```
 public class ToRealCount : IValueConverter
 {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
   if (value is int count)
   {
    return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
   }
   return 0;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
 }
```

you might consider looking into this too [flipview](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/flipview)

Comment: thanks, i tried with the flipview but the control didnt work as expected, so in the end i just use a combobox instead of a listview, thanks anyway for the work.

Comment: i think combobox is acualy perfect for this , anyway i hope  my ans helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using a combobox instead of a list, because i dont want to use something hacky that could end doing weird things and flipview didnt work as intended so is actually the best.

As i have to wait anyway if someone gives a better solution would be very nice.